# Is there a way to assign a non-default mime type in the bitbucket io site?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bitbucket, mime-types, github-pages

Repositories on Bitbucket (as well as on github) can be used to host a static website with `.io` extension.

Is it possible to assign an `application/octet-stream` mime type to my `.ipynb` file so that the browser would download it instead of displaying it in the raw form?

Comment: I tried setting up an `.htaccess` file, but it doesn't seem to be working.